# Child Rows Getting removed in tree table after executing commit in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, treetable

I have a tree table in jspx page, which is based on EO and VO without database. I have added parent and child records in tree table programmatically . After executing commit operation the child rows are getting removed from the GUI. Please help me prevent this.

Comment: Are you using a POJO as datasource for your tree table? Refer to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/38-pojo-editable-tree-169180.pdf  to make sure you are accessing the tree data properly

Comment: No I am not using pojo as data source